# Mapping network share with different credentials

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

We have a Windows 2008R2 server which can be connected via Remote Desktop. We have some applications running (Scheduled / build etc) in the server

One of our application needs to copy / access files on a share which has different user credentials.

I was thinking of mapping this drive as a network drive with different credentials so that the applications can access it

My question will the mapped drive be available even after the I log out from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
net use /p:yes
net use Z: \\server\sharename
```

You should also safe your credentials in the credentials manager.